# Convergence in$L^p$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ is a measureable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lebesgue measure. Given $p \in [1,\infty)$ and $f_n \in L^p(\Omega)$ point-wise converges to $f \in \Omega$. Assume that exists $g \in L^p(\Omega)$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$, $\forall x \in \Omega$.

Are the following true of false?

1. $f \in L^p(\Omega)$
2. $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$

I see this type of exercise at the first time so i'm very confused and don't know how to do, i don't know how to know it's right or wrong and if wrong how to construct counter-example? And do you have sources of this type of exercises?

Comment: Do you know the dominated convergence theorem? Do you know the definition of "$f_n \to f $ in $L^p $"?

Comment: Yes, but the dominated convergence theorem is that $f_n \to f$ a.e?

Comment: oh ok thank you. But can you give me some sources of this type of exercises?

Comment: Every measure theory book ever written should have lots of exercises like this.  Folland's *Real Analysis" for instance.